# Retrieving data from file using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a bubble tooltip that is supposed to show user profile info when cursor is hovered over user's name. I have got it to work with hard coded text , however when I try to populate the tooltip with dynamic data using AJAX request, it just does not return anything.

The data to retrieve is in file process.cfm. The file looks like this:

```
<div class="personPopupResult">Test text</div>
```

The code that calls the file is as follows:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: 'process.cfm',  
    data: '?id=' + currentID,  
    success: function(data) {  
        var text = $(data).find('.personPopupResult').html();  
        $('#personPopupContent').html(text);  
    }  
});
```

Any ideas why this does not work would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'process.cfm?=id' + currentID,

            success: function(data){

                $('#personPopupContent').html(data);

                if ($(data).find('.personPopupResult').length) {
                    var text = $(data).find('.personPopupResult').html();
                    $('#personPopupContent').html(text);
                }

            }
        });
```

Code works, but displays everything in process.cfm page, not only .personPopupResult div.

Comment: Try with this `var text = $(data).find('.personPopupResult').text();`

Comment: Try insert alert(text), after var text .... Try vote if helpful.

Comment: I inserted `alert(text);` but it does not show up. Why would I want it to display the text? The current problem is how to limit the output to only one class.

Comment: The problem is that element $(data).find('.personPopupResult')  does not exists. You need to use another selector.

Comment: It certainly does exists:

`<div class="personPopupResult">Test</div>`

Comment: Then you need to use following:  $('.personPopupResult').html(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: 'process.cfm?=id' + currentID,   

    success: function(data) {  
        //actually here you should better write following
        //$('#personPopupContent').html(data); 
        // but if not works try this
        if ($('#personPopupContent').length)
        {
          alert(' $(#personPopupContent) not found!');
        }
        if ($(data).find('.personPopupResult').length)
        {
        var text = $(data).find('.personPopupResult').html();  
        $('#personPopupContent').html(data);  
         }
       else
        {
        $('#personPopupContent').html('Ups error here!');  
       }
    }  
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You pass in "data" argument into the function, but you did not declare it. Doesn't seem right to me.

BTW, I should have mentioned for clarification: the final application will use id to retrieve user's data, but right now I want to get it to work just with text.

Comment: data should not be declared. Its default. Is data = '23' (equal number)?

Comment: See my edit in the first post. The code works, but displays everything in process.cfm.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `jQuery` object with:

```
console.log($('#personPopupContent'));
```

Does it have targeted element within?

Comment: would be better if that was a comment rather than an answer